# Updating TextView from outside the Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to Java and Android and I'm currently trying **to update a `TextView` outside of my `Fragment`**.

```
// Update Location after processing location info

Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;    
TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.location) ;
String updatedLocation = cityName+" - "+cityLatitude + " " + cityLongitude;
textView.setText(updatedLocation);
```

However this does not work and the `TextView` does not update. Updating the `textview` inside `onCreateView()` works fine, but I am trying to dynamically change the contents every time I do a query to the database.

I have tried making a method in said `fragment`, but it didn't work out because the method has to be `static` and `getActivity()` is not a `static` method.

Is there another workaround for this?

Comment: you should implement an interface for changing the data between activity and fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your fragment make this function

```
public void updatecount(int counter){   
            count = counter;
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
```

and call this from different activity by initiating the object of the fragment

```
 LeftSliderFragment fragment = (LeftSliderFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);

   fragment.updatecount(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

put in color.xml your color like

```
<color name="mytextColor">#B49228</color>
```

and use `android:textColor="@color/mytextColor"`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in fragment, such as updateText(..). Use getFragmentManager:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.updateText(text);
```